# buttons in Avalonia UI are not clickable

Tags: c#, xml, xaml, avaloniaui, avalonia

I have a training project in Avalonia.
There is a MainPage, a HomePage and a TestPage page
MainPageViewModel contains the code to change the page to HomePage, but when I wanted to switch from HomePage to TestPage I got an error.
Error CS7036 There is no argument given that corresponds to the required parameter 'navigationService' of 'HomePageViewModel.HomePageViewModel(INavigationService)'.
I solved it by adding an empty class constructor to HomePageViewModel and this error disappeared (now I removed this constructor, because I want to ask how correct this solution is), but when this constructor was still there was another problem, switching from MainPage to HomePage worked, but switching from HomePage to TestPage did not, there are just gray buttons that are not even pressed.
The routing system is located in the Services folder

here is a link to the github project

https://github.com/Zakarayaev/AvaloniaApplication6

I apologize for my English as it is not my native language.

Although I've been digging through the Avalonia documentation I've found almost nothing on the Avalonia Community Toolkit, it's almost all about ReactiveUI.